# Pulling Coordinates from Mouse

Tags: c#, .net, screenshot

I'm working on a Screenshot Application(The one I liked, the developer dropped it).
Any whoo, I have the hot-key done, as well as saving the bmp->png and uploading it to my server. But I'm just not sure how to go about making a function that...

1. Freeze the Screen(Or rather, could I create some sort translucent overlay/window?)
2. Detects whether the user Left or Right Clicked on the Mouse
3. If the user right clicks, the screen is unfrozen and screenshot process is canceled
4. If the user left clicks it creates a border(1-2px) around the square(the screenshot area)
5. Pull the Coordinates(x, y) and width & height into integers

If anyone could give me some sort of direction, or where I should start looking around in the documentation I'd appreciate it.

Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want the screen to freeze?

Comment: "Freeze" is the best way I could describe it. Basicly, I'd like the active screen/monitor to "freeze" so that no action can be done until the screenshot is taken(To preserve whatever the user wants to capture).

Comment: The capturing process takes a less than 200ms on slow computers (rough estimation). Even when using the PrintScreen key to capture a video, you expect a slight error margin in the timing. The user shouldn't expect perfectly timed screen capturing just as it wouldn't expect screen freezing. Either way, you simply cannot ensure that other programs will not alter display during your supposed "frozen" time.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So an overlay wouldn't be necessary. But that brings me back to my question, how would I actually go about pulling selected screen coordinates, in addition to with & height.

Comment: That's a simple question of capturing a screen. The internet is filled with answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture part of a screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241220/how-to-capture-part-of-a-screen)

Comment: No, my problem is that I need the user to be able to select an area(to capture) and retrieve those coordinates along with the width and height. Not just capture the entire screen and have a fixed area of capture.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/219563/OneNote-Style-Screen-Capture-Utility